# Put cursor inside print macro in ConEmu

Tags: cmd, macros, conemu, cmder

Is it possible put cursor inside print macro in ConEmu?

Like this: `print("git commit -m \"${cursor}\"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. But you may move cursor afterwards via [Keys("Left","Left")](https://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Keys)